# iptables: host/network not found with multiple sources and destinations

Tags: iptables

When I try to run this command:

```
iptables -A FORWARD -p tcp --dport 22 -s 1.2.4.0/24,9.2.3.0/24 -d 1.2.3.1,1.2.3.2 -j ACCEPT
```

I get this error:

```
iptables v1.4.1.1: host/network `1.2.4.0/24,9.2.3.0' not found
```

However, if I run all 4 rules using 4 separate commands, I have no problem. Doesn't iptables support multiple sources and destinations addresses using the comma?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*iptables* 1.4.1.1 has been released on 2008-06-06: almost 12 years ago. So when checking manuals, the manual for its own version should be checked. After downloading the source from https://netfilter.org/projects/iptables/files/iptables-1.4.1.1.tar.bz2 or looking at: https://git.netfilter.org/iptables/tree/iptables.8.in?h=v1.4.1.1#n271, here's the man page source's content:

> `-s, --source [!] address[/mask]`
>
> Source specification.  Address can be either a network name, a hostname
>   [...]

1.8.2's [man page](https://manpages.debian.org/buster/iptables/iptables.8):

> `[!] -s, --source address[/mask][,...]`
>
> Source specification. Address can be either a network name, a hostname
>   [...]
>    Multiple addresses can be specified, but this **will expand to multiple rules**
>   [...]

The older version simply doesn't support multiple addresses. There's no technical difference in the end: it's the same as providing 4 (2x2) rules.

Please upgrade your OS. There's probably no support anymore.

Comment: Thanks! This was really naive